# Як правильно - "бітний" чи "бітовий", "бітність" чи "бітовість"?

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

Пошук в інтернеті видає винятково [бітність](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&*), але чому не [бітовість](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&*). Натомість маємо

- [Бітовий зсув](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2)
- [Бітові операції](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97)
- [Бітовий потік](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BA)

Як правильно, яке правило це регулює?

Ось знайшов давнє обговорення на LOU - [бітний чи бітовий](http://linux.org.ua/index.php?topic=930.0)

Comment: В російській мові «битный» вживається винятково коли кажемо про кількість («16-битный»), а «битовый» — в тому числі коли кажемо про якість («битовая маская»). Аналогічно «кутн{и,і}й» — може бути і про кількість («трикутний, чотирикутний»), і про якість («кутні зуби»), а «кутовий» — лише про якість («кутовий удар»). Хоча у випадку укр. «бітний»/«бітовий» більший безлад, ніж в укр. «кут*» і рос. «бит*».

Comment: Тим не менш «бітний» використовується *лише* про кількість (але «бітовий» — в цьому значенні теж). «Бітність» — це кількість бітів (хоча навіть у рос. іноді вживається «битовость»). «Бітовий зсув», «бітові операції» і «бітовий потік» — це характеристика (а не «текстовий» чи «тритовий»). «Сама бітовість цього потоку під сумнівом» — це коли потік веде себе не зовсім як бітовий (на відміну від: «бітність регістру мені невідома» — це коли мені невідомо, 8 чи 18 чи скільки в ньому бітів). Хоча «бітовий» часто використовують як гіперонім до «бітний» (тож, може, «бітовість» теж припустимо).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Пень слова від [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit), уникає [девʼятку](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) і не має чергування. Лоґічне поняття.
- Отже розглянемо наростки за досовєцькі часи. Проблема [не нова.](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/)

> ## [Норми української літературної мови](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky)
>
> Львів – 1941 (друге видання), [Олекса Синявський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). На основі клясичного або харківського правопису [1928](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81).
>
> ### § 100.31 *-ний*, *-нїй*
>
> Найширше вживаний наросток при різних пнях і з різноманїтним значінням:
>
> - при іменникових пнях на означення **матеріялу**, далї **відношення**, **ґатунку**, **властивости** (але в меншій мірі, як **-астий**, **-истий**): *молочний, пшеничний, залїзний, камінний, мідний, розумний, бездоганний, срібний, житнїй, оксамитний, будївельний, народнїй, барвний*... (отже наближається значінням, а инодї й спадається з **-овий**, **-яний**).
>
> Від деяких із таких прикметників відокремлюється категорія «багатий на щось», звичайно з переходом наголосу на **-ний**:
>
> *ри́бний (ловець) — рибна́ (річка)
>
>   хлїбний (квас) — хлїбни́й (край)
>
>   (лїсови́й)  — лїсни́й (край)
>
>   (снїгови́й) — снїжна́ (зима)
>
>   (медо́вий) — медни́й (рік)
>
>   (людо́вий) — людни́й (базар)
>
>   (горови́й і гі́рний) — гірна́ (країна)
>
>   (хмарови́й і хма́рний) — хмарни́й (день)
>
>                              — звірни́й (лїс)*
>
> Зокрема **-ний** часто буває в словах чужомовного походження, при тїм инодї з чужомовними перед ним наростками **-ив-**, **-атив-** тощо: активний, оперативний, ілюстративний...
>
> ### § 100.34 *-овий* (*-йовий*), *-евий* (*-євий*)
>
> Досить поширений наросток на означення відносних прикметників, отже тїльки при іменникових пнях:
>
> - на питання «з чого?», «який?», рідко «чий?»: *дубо́вий, соболе́вий, їжако́вий, воло́вий, вербо́вий, паперо́вий, ли́совий, орло́вий, лойови́й, смуше́вий, груше́вий, бає́вий, кри́це́вий, овоче́вий* (порівн. **-иний**, **-ячий**, **-яний**).
> - на питання «який?» «до чого відносний?» (прикметники відношення): *науко́вий, службо́вий, рокови́й, шляхови́й, верствови́й, загадко́вий, випадко́вий, степови́й, дощови́й, багаже́вий*...
>
> Взагалї наросток **-овий** у таких значіннях часто чергується з иншими прикметниковими наростками, зокрема з **-ний**, при тїм часто й значіння слова зміняється з зміною наростка, але не так, щоб можна було визначити відмінність **-овий** супроти инших, напр.: *розумо́вий* (прикметник відносний) — *розу́мний* (инше значіння, між иншим, з ступенюванням — *розумнїший*...), *вагови́й — ва́жний*, але в *рокови́й — рі́чний*, *оксамитовий — оксамитний*... вже немає такої відмінности.
>
> ### § 99.57 *-ість*, *-ощі*
>
> Дуже поширенї наростки (на означення властивости абстрактно і звичайно від прикметників): *ра́дїсть (радости), ста́рість, пе́внїсть, злїсть, му́жнїсть, неоха́йнїсть, брехли́вість, бі́льшість, дїя́льність*... **-ощі** надає конкретнішого значіння: *ра́дощі, пе́стощі, лю́бощі, хи́трощі, го́рдощі, пу́стощі, ла́сощі...*

## Отже

- **біт-н-ість** як кількість:

  > [Розрядність](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (**бітність**) в інформатиці — **кількість** розрядів (бітів) електронного.
- **біт-ов-ість** як харастиристика. Приклад від мене:

  > Роботи знищують все, що бітовість не контролює.

Краще писати одразу через відносника — *біт*, якщо не хочете підкреслити харастеристику (абстракність). Порівняйте на минулому прикладї: не *розумовість*, а *розум*.

## Про всяк

- **Бітний** зсув — [одноразовий] зсув на біту
- **Бітовий** зсув — характеристика зсуву