# Як правильно "блоковий" чи "блочний"

Tags: вибір-слова

e2u віддає перевагу [блоковий](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=all&highlight=on) перед [блочний](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=all&highlight=on)

[image]

> **block** = [blɒk] **1.** блок; гру́па; ву́зол || **бло́ковий** || розбива́ти/розби́ти на бло́ки, об’є́днувати/об’єдна́ти в бло́ки,
>   зво́дити/зве́сти́ до бло́кової фо́рми // **in ~s** гру́пами; бло́ками
>   **2.** блокува́ти/заблокува́ти

Але в інтернеті можна бачити обидва варіанти. Як правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Словник УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)

- блоковий *(від: блок — угода)*
- блочний *(від: блок — механізм)*

---

Орфографічний словник української мови

- [блоковий](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53393/43646.html) *(від: блок — механізм, угода)*
- [блочний](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53393/43662.html) *(від: блок — механізм, плита)*

---

Тлумачний словник української мови у 20 томах

- блоковий

  1. [Прикм.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4793&page=181) до блок<sup>1</sup>. *Блоковий спосіб скиртування.*
  2. *спец.* [Прикм.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4794&page=181) до блок<sup>2</sup>. *Блокова будова.*
  3. - *політ.* [Прикм.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191802&page=181) до блок<sup>3</sup>. *Виглядало на те, що всіх влаштовує блоковий статус. Зрештою, політики дійшли висновку, що пріоритетом є перемога на президентських виборах* (з газ.).
     - Прикм. до блок<sup>3</sup>. *Блокову структуру телевізійної програми було змінено* (з газ.).
- блочний

  1. [Прикм.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=189413&page=181) до блок<sup>1</sup>. *Автонавантажувач, обладнаний блочною стрілою, застосовується в портах, доках і на будівельних майданчиках* (з наук.-попул. літ.).
  2. *спец.* [Прикм.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=189414&page=181) до блок<sup>2</sup>. *Блочний матеріал*; ／ Який складається зі стандартних блоків. *Блочні теплиці — це обʼєднання двосхилих теплиць, у яких немає проміжків між секціями, а бокові простінки замінені стояками* (з наук. літ.).
- блок

  1. [*-а (родовий відмінок)*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4784&page=180) Простий механізм для підняття важких предметів, що має форму колеса (на осі) з жолобом, через яке перекинуто ланцюг, канат і т. ін. *Міни лежать на палубі й у трюмі, .. блоками опускають їх у морську дорогу* (Ю. Яновський); *Вітер гуляє у вітах каштанів... Ніжно посвистує блоками кранів* (М. Гірник); *Слуги ввозили заморські фрукти в вазах з чистого золота і таких важких, що підіймати їх на столи доводилось на обшитих позолоченою шкірою вірьовках, перекинутих через блоки, хитро сховані під стелею* (П. Загребельний).
  2. [*-а (родовий відмінок)*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4785&page=180)

     - *техн.* Окрема, незалежна частина споруди, машини і т. ін., що складається також з окремих елементів або деталей. *„Прикарпатліс“ — один з провідних постачальників на ринок України пиломатеріалів, дверних та віконних блоків* (із журн.).
     - *буд.* Природний або штучний будівельний камінь, порізаний на плити. *Грубезні його [храму] стіни, муровані з камʼяних блоків, були .. побілені вапном* (Р. Федорів); *Учені різних країн давно ламають голову над секретом Хеміуна: як він умудрився змонтувати гігантські камʼяні блоки піраміди Хеопса* (з наук. літ.); *З різних глин виготовляють керамічні блоки для стін, панелей та перекриттів* (з наук.-попул. літ.).
     - Упакування, що містить кілька (багато) однакових предметів. *Якби злочинець навідався вчора чи наступного дня, то його здобиччю було б не більше десятка блоків сигарет* (з газ.).
  3. [*-у (родовий відмінок)*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4786&page=180)

     - *політ.* Обʼєднання держав, організацій, партій і т. ін. *НАТО — військово-політичний блок, до якого на час створення входили США, Великобританія, Франція, Італія, Канада та інші країни* (з навч. літ.); *Чимало народних депутатів запевняють, мовляв, проголосуйте за мене чи мій виборчий блок, і питання із вкладами Ощадбанку СРСР буде знято* (з газ.).
     - Серія однотипних теле- або радіопрограм, переданих одна за одною, або кілька друкованих матеріалів на одну тему. *Одна з частин нової телепрограми — щоденний блок спортивних новин* (з газ.).
     - Логічно завершена частина певної програми або переліку дій. *Посібник складається з чотирьох блоків, до яких увійшли інтерактивні вправи, апробовані під час реалізації проекту* (з навч. літ.).

---

[Норми української літературної мови](http://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) ([Олекса Синявський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), 1941)

31. **-ний**, **-ній** — найширше вживаний [наросток](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/) при різних пнях і з різноманітним значінням:

а) при іменникових пнях на означення *матеріялу*, далі *відношення*, *ґатунку*, *властивости* (але в меншій мірі, як **-астий**, **-истий**): *молочний, пшеничний, залізний, камінний, мідний, розумний, бездоганний, срібний, житній, оксамитний, будівельний, народній, барвний* (отже наближається значінням, а іноді й спадається з **-овий**, **-яний**).

Від деяких із таких прикметників відокремлюється категорія „багатий на щось“, звичайно з переходом наголосу на **-ний**:

*рибний (ловець) — рибна (річка)

хлібний (квас) — хлібний (край)

(лісовий)  — лісний (край)

(сніговий) — сніжна (зима)

(медовий) — медний (рік)

(людовий) — людний (базар)

(горовий і гірний) — гірна (країна)

(хмаровий і хмарний) — хмарний (день)

                           — звірний (ліс)*

Зокрема **-ний** часто буває в словах чужомовного походження, при тім іноді з чужомовними перед ним наростками **-ив-**, **-атив-** тощо: *активний*, *оперативний*, *ілюстративний*.

б) при дієслівних пнях на означення прикметників, іноді близьких значінням до загублених дієприкметників переємних теперішнього часу, а почасти й минулого: *прохідний, наступний, доступний, пожи́вний, придатний, чутний, непохитний, незабутній, наступний, непробудний* і т. ін. — див. § 89.3 дрібн. шрифт.

в) при прислівникових пнях часто з **ш** перед **-ній**: *горішній, долішній, колишній, теперішній, тутешній, домашній, справдешній* — див. § 54.

г) в дієприкметниках переємних минулого часу: *даний*, *караний*, *улюблений*, *засвоєний*... — див. § 89.

34. **-овий** (**-йовий**), **-евий** (**-євий**) — досить поширений наросток на означення відносних прикметників, отже тільки при іменникових пнях:

а) на питання „з чого?“, „який?“, рідко „чий?“: *дубовий, соболевий, їжаковий, воловий, вербовий, паперовий, ли́совий, орловий, лойовий, смушевий, грушевий, баєвий, крицевий, овочевий* (порівн. **-иний, -ячий, -яний**).

б) на питання „який?“ „до чого відносний?“ (прикметники відношення): *науковий, службовий, роковий, шляховий, верствовий, загадковий, випадковий, степовий, дощовий, багажевий...*

Взагалі наросток **-овий** у значінні і а) і б) часто чергується з іншими прикметниковими наростками, зокрема з **-ний**, при тім часто й значіння слова зміняється з зміною наростка, але не так, щоб можна було визначити відмінність **-овий** супроти інших, напр.: *розумовий* (прикметник відносний) — *розумний* (інше значіння, між іншим, з ступенюванням — *розумніший*), *ваговий* — *важний*, але в *роковий* — *річний*, *оксамитовий* — *оксамитний* вже немає такої відмінности.

---

Моя думка

Результати вказують, що все залежить від контексту:

- Блочний — може замінювати слово [складний](http://sum.in.ua/s/skladnyj).
- Блоковий — включає значення „блочний“ (вказує яка є „система“) й має відношення до всіх „блоків“, чого не сказати про „блочний“.

Але я вважаю, що правильно й більш є логічним — *блоковий*.

---

Подібне

- [How to choose between the changing consonants in the root?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4/)

Comment: що таке *пні* і *наростки*?

Comment: @Follower а звідки походить така термінолоґія? Дуже цікаво, ніколи не бачив.