# Мовознавча термінолоґія

Tags: альтернативні-правописи, означення

Причина створення — [запитання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/#comment4313_2586)

> — Що таке *пні* і *наростки*?
>   — Звідки походить така термінолоґія? Ніколи не бачив.

Тут все про мовознавчу термінолоґію, включно давні.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64198/discussion-on-question-by-follower--).

Answer (score 7):

#### [Митрофан Дикарів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)
<sub>(наприклад: [лист Грушевському](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Starkov_Valerii/Lysty_Mytrofana_ta_Uliany_Dykarevykh_do_Mykhaila_Hrushevskoho/) від 31.05.1896 (ст. 487–488), [«Мітольоґічні уривки»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Dykariv_Mytrofan/Posmertni_pysannia_Mytrofana_Dykareva_z_polia_folkloru_i_mitolohii/) (ст. 200))</sub>

- звуки:

  - *самоголос* — [голосний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA)
  - *суголос* — [приголосний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA)

#### [Руска правопись, Степан Смаль-Стоцький, 1892](https://zbruc.eu/node/66463)

- звуки:

  - *самозвук* — [голосний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA)
  - *співзвук* — [приголосний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA)
  - *двозвук* — [дифтонґ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3)
  - *безголосий* — [глухий](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
- частини слова:

  - *приставка* — [префікс](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81)
  - *пень* — [основа слова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)
  - *наросток* — [суфікс](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81)
- частини мови:

  - *приложник* — [прикметник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)
- члени речення:

  - *приложенє* — [прикладка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- орфографічні знаки:

  - *роздїлка* — [дефіс](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%96%D1%81)
- *перепинанє* — пунктуація:

  - *протинка* або *за́пинка* — [кома](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA))
  - *знак серединий* — [крапка з комою](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E)
  - *павза* — [тире](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)
  - *знаки наведеня* — [лапки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)
  - *питайник* — [знак питання](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)
  - *окличник* — [знак оклику](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)

#### [Український правопис, Народній комісаріят освіти У. С. Р. Р., Харків, 1929](http://r2u.org.ua/node/181)
<sub>(також відомий як [харківський правопис, правопис Голоскевича або скрипниківка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81)), [Українсько-Російський словник](https://r2u.org.ua/node/266)</sub>

- частини слова:

  - *приросток* — [префікс](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81)
  - *пень* — [основа слова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)
  - *наросток* — [суфікс](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81)
- *помічні при альфабеті знаки*, окрім розділових:

  - *розділка* — [дефіс](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%96%D1%81)
- пунктуація:

  - *середник* — [крапка з комою](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E)
  - *риска* — [тире](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)

Comment: НМД, на цю відповідь навіть не обовʼязково було ставити CW статус. CW — це для того, щоб будь-хто міг вносити правки без необхідності узгоджувати це з автором допису. У даному випадку, йдеться про термінологію, яку використовують конкретні словники, і я так розумію, що їх є сталий список.